# Paste to clipboard along with powerpaste in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, copy-paste, tinymce-plugins

Is it possible to use paste and powerpaste plugin together? It's much needed in my application. As far as I tried, both doesn't goes hand in hand to provide me the expected solution. Any workaround is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need both plugins enabled? PowerPaste should do everything the Paste plugin does and more.

Comment: Yeah I know. But in my application, pasting from other sources like notepad or any other source apart from office , excel should have the option to keep formatting. Simple paste also needed. It's a requirement from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

If а you are using TInyMCE with premium plugins such as PowerPaste, you can submit the Support ticket [on the portal](https://support.tiny.cloud/hc/en-us/requests/new). The tinyMCE team will reply shortly.

If you need to control how the content is pasted, please check the [powerpaste_html_import](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/powerpaste-options/#powerpaste_html_import), [powerpaste_word_import](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/powerpaste-options/#powerpaste_word_import), and [powerpaste_googledocs_import](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/powerpaste-options/#powerpaste_googledocs_import) options. If they are not set to default in your config - either remove them or set them to `prompt` - this way TinyMCE will ask the user if it is needed to clean or merge the formatting on each paste.